# I want to create a mysql query which select only if previous 3 record's status has been changed

Tags: php, mysql

I have an ordering system and wishing to automatically send new orders to my riders.

So far I achieved this with some query and loop and checking what to send to who.

This is my current mysql query look like

```
SELECT a.ID, b.RiderID FROM `order` AS a
            LEFT OUTER JOIN rider_online_order AS b ON a.ID = b.OrderID
            WHERE a.Status = "OnList" ORDER BY a.ID ASC
```

It returns something like this

```
| ID    | RiderID|
|-------|--------|
|  1223 |   9    |
|  1223 |  81    |
|  1224 |  9     |
|  1225 |  4     |
|  1225 |  NULL  |
```

Order Table Relevant Fields

```
| ID   | Status |
|------|--------|
| 1223 | OnList |
| 1224 | Rider_Assigned |
| 1225 | OnList |
| 1226 | OnList |
| 1227 | OnList |
| 1228 | OnList |
```

Rider Tabel Relevant Fields

```
| ID   | Status |
| 4    | Online |
| 9    | Busy   |
| 81   | Online |
```

Which tells me which order is enlist to be sent and has been sent to who so I shouldn't send him again. Then I have some php loops to check various things and sending new orders to riders through sms.

Once they received an order number they replied with a short code and order number then system assign those orders to their name change `order`.`Status to "Rider_Assigned" and change rider Status to "busy" so I know he got this order and no one else can take this order. Also we shouldn't send him another order until he is free.

SO far so good...

Now here is the problem

I have sent 3 orders to 4 different riders and none of them actually replied with short code and order number so status of all 3 orders remain "OnList" so I don't want to send anymore orders to anyone until that's done.

One way I can think of is looping through on server and ignore request but I want to achieve this with MySql query if possible.

Anyone can help? really appreciate it

Comment: why don't you use  ORDER BY a.ID DESC limt 3 at the end of the query ?

Comment: I would be a lot easier to understand your actual requirement if you had include some sample data from both tables along with expected result set.

Comment: create another column `request_send`(change name accordingly). when sending request put `send` in that column and when user respond back change that to `complete` . then change your query and add `where request_send !='send' OR request_send !='completed'  `

Comment: @BunkerBoy I don't want last 3 orders. I want orders that is next in line so if I have order 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and 1, 3, 4 has been sent and changed status I want to send 2, 5, 6

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos ok I'm updating it to add some more data

Comment: opps sorry you can i think @ Alive to Die way is right

Comment: @AlivetoDie that's not the problem. Sending is fine and I know what to send. I don't want to send until old orders changed status. So if I have 3 riders online and 6 orders. I want to stop sending orders after 3 until first 3 orders changed status to "Rider_Assigned"

Comment: Should be simple. Add a table that tracks messages sent. It would have the rider ID and order ID. Only send messages that aren't in that table. You simply left join the order table and sent table, and select only those with a null sent row.

Comment: @AlivetoDie not really coz one rider was busy and he just got free so he need to get that order too which hasn't changed status.

Comment: @SloanThrasher This is exactly what I am doing right now. Problem is I don't want to send all orders unless previous orders changed status